# What does this backslash do in this assembly code?

Tags: gcc, assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I am not sure what the difference is in these push lines. (trimmed down [from Linux's x86/entry/calling.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/241e39004581475b2802cd63c111fec43bb0123e/arch/x86/entry/calling.h#L100), with the xor-zero clearing removed.)

```
.macro PUSH_AND_CLEAR_REGS rdx=%rdx rax=%rax save_ret=0
    pushq \rdx
    pushq \rax
    pushq %r11
    pushq %r12
.endm
```

Do both push onto the stack? Or do the first two push lines do something different? I am on linux using the GNU toolchain.

These lines where found in a `.h` file that's included by `.S` asm source files.

Also can anyone tell me what this code does?

```
.macro PUSH_AND_CLEAR_REGS rdx=%rdx rax=%rax save_ret=0
```

Specifically the code after PUSH_AND_CLEAR_REGS.

Comment: It's better to ask two question separately. There might be people knowing the answer for one of them only.

Comment: Copy-paste your code, don't retype it.  `%rll` (with two ells) is not a register name, but `%r11` is.  It's not plausible that there's another asm macro somewhere that will make `%rll` actually compile.

Comment: Have you tried reading the assembler manual to find out what this does?

Answer (score 3):

Inside [a GAS `.macro`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html#Macro), you use `\foo` to refer to a macro parameter called `foo`.

The `.macro` you're looking at has 3 args with default values; presumably in some use-case they want to get alternate values saved in place of what's actually in RAX and RDX.  But the rest of the registers get saved and xor-zeroed as normal.

So after macro expansion, yes it's just `push %rdx` and `push %rax`, same as the `push %r11` and `push %r12`.

---

IDK if you were looking at an old version of Linux, but this is in a `.h` that's included by other `.S` hand-written asm source files, *not* by `.c` sources.  I fixed your question for you.

I thought the comment on the GAS macro definition was was pretty clear about the purpose of this macro.  See the github link I added to your question.